# Running a simple Qt example in android with c4droid

Tags: android, qt

I'm new to Qt, and I have been using C4droid for a while, until I discovered the possibility of compiling and running Qt apps directly from my phone. The first time I tried installing the Qt libraries on the phone I had problems, but two days ago I was able to succesfully install them, so I tried the included Qt example, a Hello World, it compiles, but when I try to run it, my phone only gets to the screen with the Ministro logo in the background, and then it shows the error message:

> "Your application encountered a fatal error and cannot continue."

It does not say anything else, and I don't know if there's a .log file somewhere. So if there's anyone with more experience I would really appreciate some help. Sorry for my bad english.

My phone it's a Samsung Galaxy Ace, it's an old phone, maybe that could be the reason. I'm only trying with the C4droid included Hello World Qt example, so it's supposed to work. All of the others examples works without problems, even the SDL ones.